# How to attach extra data to user (for password reset) with Kuzzle

Tags: node.js, kuzzle

I want to make a reset password feature on a Kuzzle stack but I don't know where to put extra data (like a token for reset password) in the user document.

Furthermore, the user should not be able to change the data itself.

Should I use [`security.updateUser`](https://docs.kuzzle.io/api/1/controller-security/update-user/) endpoint and prevent user access with a hook or a pipe ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can use the security.updateUser endpoint to add extra data to your user.

What you can do to prevent the user itself to change his data is either create a role which forbid access to the controller `security` and action `updateUser` (see https://docs.kuzzle.io/guide/1/essentials/security) or make a pipe plugin on `before:updateUser` which will remove the extra data from the query if present (see https://docs.kuzzle.io/plugins/1/essentials/pipes)

Full disclosure: I work at Kuzzle